# How to properly use a UITabBarController in Monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I understand what to do when using a UITabBarController with the MainWindow. But if when I'm in IB and I decide I want to have a UITabBarController, I only ever get a UIViewController that has a UITabBarController. If this is how it needs to be, then when do I .AddSubView of the UITabBarController? In the ViewWillLoad of the UIViewController? Do I just change the class that is inherited from in the code?

Bit lost here.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not think I get your question. Are you trying to add a UITabBarController in another UIViewController?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how I am supposed to use the IB UITabBarController vs. UITabBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do:

- derive from UITabBarController in IB
- add the new class to my XIB
- (if I want to add new tabs outside of IB, I override LoadView in my tab bar controller class and do it in there)
- in AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching, I add my tab bar's view as a subview of 'window' (ie window.AddSubview(mainTabBar.View); )

Those steps work for me without any obvious problems.

Comment: It's what to do when you aren't using the Window to add the subview to. Is it the same when you do this to a View?